# my credit card leaked

Tags: security, firewall, virus, trojan

I got a phone call from someone pretend from Amazon and he want to confirm my credit card so he asked the expire date and security code when I refused he give me full name, address, last 4 digits of my credit card but Amzon confirm they never call a customer for these information !! how all these info are leaked ?

I use Kaspersky Internet security and also did scan with spyware doctor but did not found viruses or worms !!

I canceled my credit card and changed all my passwords but please advise what I should do to secure my data

Thanks

Comment: You have my sympathies, but what are you trying to ask here?  What do you mean to "secure [your] data"?

Comment: secure my data to prevent these from happening again

Comment: Change all yourpasswords. You did  the rest by canceling cards. I would do that with any ATMs as well.

Comment: @Welliam: If you posted this question using a different account and you want to regain control of it, you can [request to merge your profiles](http://superuser.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 2):

This might be obvious, but: Why do you assume that the credit card information leaked via the computer? If the computer is infected and someone intercepted all information when you did on-line shopping they would not need to ask for the security code.

Having said that:

1. Do make sure your computer is secure. If for nothing else than to prevent similar problems in the future. Note that the best way to check for an infection is without booting the potentially infected OS. (E.g. use a liveCD).
2. Do not use the same password at multiple locations. That way you only have to change one password if it leaks.
3. Do store passwords in a secure way (An e-wallet might be handy. That is a class of programs which store your passwords in a secure way. You need one (good!) pass-phrase to unlock the store. Compare it to a an Excell sheat  with passwords where you need a password to open the file. You only need to remember one password to get to the list, yet can use different passwords on each site.).
4. Most credit cards have additional one time security checks (E.g. the *verified by visa* code.) Make sure you enable that on your next credit card.

Comment: in no 4. what you mean by one time security check ?

Comment: If I order something on-line I have to enter my CC number, the verification code on the back and enter a password. The CC number is fixed, if that gets stolen I have a problem. Same for the 3 digit number on the back, but the third one is a password which I can change. If you change that after each purchase then you never hand out enough information for a potential thief to do future purchases with your credit card information.

Comment: Thanks Hennes, I only use my card on Amazon and pay my bills....do you know a security tool I can use to check my system ?